# How to compress image file size laravel

Tags: php, image, laravel, amazon-s3

I have some images in my S3 bucket on AWS. I am trying to get the images and send them to my android app (along with other information from my database). My current setup works fine but I would like to reduce the image file sizes (currently around 1-1.5mb) before I send them to the app.

I have tried to use this code:

```
function compress($source, $destination, $quality) {

    $info = getimagesize($source);

    if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') 
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);

    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') 
        $image = imagecreatefromgif($source);

    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') 
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);

    imagejpeg($image, $destination, $quality);

    return $destination;
}

$image_file = Storage::disk('s3_upload')->get("s3bucketpath");

$new_image_file = $this->replace_extension($image->filename, '.jpg');

$this->compress($image_file,$new_image_file, 50);
```

I get

```
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in file
```

error from

```
$info = getimagesize($source);
```

I have checked the file path and it is in the bucket and exists and I have var-dumped source and gotten

```
����&#0;JFIF&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;��&#0;C&#0;$&lt;&#39;$!!$J58,&lt;XM\[VMUSam�vag�hSUy�z������^t�����������&#0;C$ $G&#39;&#39;G�dUd����������������������������������������������������&#0;@0&quot;&#0;��&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;��&#0;A&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;!1A&quot;Q2aq#B���3R�$4b�rC���%S���5D���&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;��&#0;#&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;!1A2&quot;Q#��&#0;&#0;&#0;?&#0;��HS-�&#0; &#0;&#0;&#0; &#0;&#0;B�@&#0;)&#0;&#0;(  @�&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#10;@&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;!@&#0;&#0;��&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;��&#0;��&#0;(&#0;�&#0;�&#0;(&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;� �&#10;@�&#0;&#0;&#0;UF�LHU@�d ��&#10;@ &#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;�)&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;@R&#0;&#0;B�&#0;&#0;&#0;(&#0;R&#0;&#0;�E]��(&#10;&#10;(� @B'...
```

What is the best way to go about doing this.

Comment: are solve this problem

Comment: Can you please tell us how you solved this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Try http://image.intervention.io/ to compress file.
It is simple and efficient.

Compression details:
http://image.intervention.io/api/encode

How to start? Simply:

```
// include composer autoload
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

// import the Intervention Image Manager Class
use Intervention\Image\ImageManager;

// create an image manager instance with favored driver
$manager = new ImageManager(array('driver' => 'imagick'));

// to finally create image instances
$image = $manager->make('public/foo.jpg')->resize(300, 200);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are really serious about compressing and resizing your images, you can use libraries like [PNGQuant](https://pngquant.org/install.html) for [**`PNG compression`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44292233/2289953)  without losing the quality and [jpegoptim](https://github.com/tjko/jpegoptim) for `jpeg` images.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this solution please:

[How to compress image before uploading in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42411140/how-to-compress-image-before-uploading-in-laravel)

Here is the library suggested in case you don't want to go to this page first

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-image-optimizer